# jquery load and retain functions

Tags: jquery

Currently I am using jquery .load to display some images in a new popup div on my website when a link is clicked, the code is as follows.

```
$(".more_images").click(function () {
    $("#uploads").show("slow", function () {
        $("#uploads").load("http://www.sunshinecoastdetailing.com.au/uploads", function () {
            $(".i_img").click(function () {
                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                $("#uploads").load(url, function () {
                    $(document).watermark();
                    $("#uploads").click(function () {
                        $("#uploads").fadeOut(300);
                    });
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

The callback function then allows an image to be clicked and loaded into the same div.
My question is, I'd like to have a back button and somehow preserve the function to still click the images and load them in the same div, remembering the .load content isn't loading jquery, hence the functions need to be preserved somehow.

I realise there are plugins that exist, but I'd rather keep it simple if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really test it with jsfiddle but would something like this work?

Have two divs and load the html into a variable and change the 2nd div. When the button is clicked hide the button and reset the html of the 2nd div.

html:

```
<button id="more_images">More Images</button>
<div id="uploads" style="display:none;">Images:
    <div id="uploadImages"></div>
    <button id="goBack" style="display:none">Back</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#more_images").click(function () {
    $("#uploads").show("slow", function () {
        $.get("http://www.sunshinecoastdetailing.com.au/uploads", function( imgHtml ) {
            $("#uploadImages").html(imgHtml);
            $("#uploadImages").on("click", ".i_img", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $(this).attr("href");

                $("#uploadImages").load(url, function () {
                    $("#goBack").toggle();
                    $("#goBack").click(function () {
                        $("#uploadImages").html(imgHtml);
                        $("#goBack").toggle();
                    });
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you try what I had in the answer? Instead of $("#uploads").load(url) try a $.get(url, function (divHtml ... so you have the divHtml inside the function so when you click the back button you can set the div's html to divHtml

Comment: Was confused as the code wasn't working, but a simple change from #more_images to a class and works perfect.